# Entity Framework model first: update data model of live database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-model-first, updatemodel

I am using ASP.Net with Entity Framework. My web forms application has gone live some time ago and now I have to write some extensions for the application. This includes updating the data model (add new columns, tables, etc.). The question is: what's the best way to do this regarding he Entity Framework? 
Since I cannot just add the new entities in the *edmx diagramm and then update the database (this would cause all existing data to be dropped), I'm wondering how to perform this task properly. The best way I can think of is to add the columns/tables manually (either directly via SQL or the SQL Management Studio) and then use the option in the designer "Update model from database". However, I do not know if this would cause the auto-generated entity classes to be updated properly?

Thanks for any pointers!